# Blockcopy for VM with multiple disks

Tags: backup, virsh

I run "virsh blockcopy ..." to backup *.qcow2 guests to a backup media. All these VM guests have no external disks associated with them.
I have another *.qcow2 guest which has two raw disks attached to it.

Currently I power off this single VM guest and copy both the "*.qcow2" file and its two associated "*.dsk" files to the backup media. I would like to automate this manual process and would like to deploy "virsh blockcopy ..." but I would like to be sure that the three files ("*.qcow2" and "*.dsk") are still **consistent** after the backup process.

Could you point me to a solution, please?

I tried a "virsh blockcopy ..." for the single "*.qcow2" file and subsequently another "virsh blockcopy ..." for each of the two "*.dsk" files. But it did not show consistency.